# Spring MVC model attribute value not printing

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I just started learning spring mvc. Trying to follow a hello world sample.
Everything seems to be working fine, except the jsp view is not able to receive the model attribute value set in the controller.

Here's some code.

Controller:

```
package org.home.webapp.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/welcome")
public class HelloController {

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String printWelcome(ModelMap model) {

    model.addAttribute("message", "Spring 3 MVC Hello World");
    return "hello";

}
}
```

View

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "    http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Hello World</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Message : ${message}</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

web.xml

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.5//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_5.dtd" >

 <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee     http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" 
 version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee">

<display-name>Spring MVC Web Application</display-name>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>
                  org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
            </listener-class>
</listener>
</web-app>
```

mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="org.home.webapp.controller" />

<bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix">
        <value>/WEB-INF/pages/</value>
    </property>
    <property name="suffix">
        <value>.jsp</value>
    </property>
</bean>

</beans>
```

Comment: Try using `Model` instead of `ModelMap`..everything looks fine..You have `hello.jsp` in `WEB-INF/pages` right?

Comment: I guess the code is from [here](http://www.mkyong.com/spring3/spring-3-mvc-hello-world-example/) :) .. make sure `hello.jsp` is present in correct location

Comment: Using the Model instead of ModelMap didn't help. The jsp is in correct location.

Comment: It might be because of old DTD used. you can resolve it by enabling the Expression Language. You can put the following code in the head section to print the value
  <%@ page isELIgnored="false" %>

Answer (score 4):

Using <%@ page isELIgnored="false" %> helped.

Answer (score 0):

We need to include org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView instead of org.springframework.web.portlet.ModelAndView;

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
public class HelloWorldController {

    @RequestMapping("/hello")
    public ModelAndView hello()
    {
        System.out.println("Just Test iNside");
        String message = "HELLO SPRING MVC HOW R U";  
        return new ModelAndView("hello", "message", message);  
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Using follwing code my issue resolved, may be its helpfull for you

Web.xml

```
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4" 
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd"> .....<web-app>
```

spring-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xsi:schemaLocation="  
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans  
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd  
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context  
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd  
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc  
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">...</beans>
```

Also added follwing dependency

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

Try this changes may be it will work for you

Answer (score 0):

you can use `<th:block th:text="${your_attribut_name}"/>`

example controller

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String printWelcome(ModelMap model) {
      model.addAttribute("message", "Spring 3 MVC Hello World");
      return "hello";
}
```

view

```
<h1>Message : <th:block th:text="${message}"/></h1>
```

output

```
Message : Spring 3 MVC Hello World
```